# How to define the type of Key-Callback pairs in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an object of Key-Callback pairs as

```
const entitiesUIEvents = {
    newEntityButtonClick: () => {
      history.push("/entity-management/entities/new");
    },
    openEditEntityDialog: (id) => {
      history.push(`/entity-management/entities/${id}/edit`);
    },
    openDeleteEntityDialog: (id) => {
      history.push(`/entity-management/entities/${id}/delete`);
    },
    openDeleteEntitysDialog: () => {
      history.push(`/entity-management/entities/deleteEntitys`);
    },
    openFetchEntitysDialog: () => {
      history.push(`/entity-management/entities/fetch`);
    },
    openUpdateEntitysStatusDialog: () => {
      history.push("/entity-management/entities/updateStatus");
    }
  }
```

Now in another React function I'm passing these callbacks as

```
 export function ActionsColumnFormatter(
    cellContent:any,
    row:Entity,
    rowIndex:number,
    { openEditEntityDialog, openDeleteEntityDialog }  // Type Error here
  ) {
    return (
      <>
        <a
          title="Edit entity"
          className="btn btn-icon btn-light btn-hover-primary btn-sm mx-3"
          onClick={() => openEditEntityDialog(row.ipAddress)}
        >
          <span className="svg-icon svg-icon-md svg-icon-primary">
            <SVG
              src={toAbsoluteUrl("/media/svg/icons/Communication/Write.svg")}
            />
          </span>
        </a>
        <> </>
  
        <a
          title="Delete entity"
          className="btn btn-icon btn-light btn-hover-danger btn-sm"
          onClick={() => openDeleteEntityDialog(row.ipAddress)}
        >
          <span className="svg-icon svg-icon-md svg-icon-danger">
            <SVG src={toAbsoluteUrl("/media/svg/icons/General/Trash.svg")} />
          </span>
        </a>
      </>
    );
  }
```

In the above code snippet `openEditEntityDialog` and `openDeleteEntityDialog` has types any. But I want them to be type safe. Please guide me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You used destructuring syntax for your callbacks.
It is easy to specify explicit type for destructured arguments.

```
export function ActionsColumnFormatter(
  cellContent:any,
  row:number,
  rowIndex:number,
  {openDeleteEntityDialog, openEditEntityDialog}: {
      openEditEntityDialog: (id: number) => void,
      openDeleteEntityDialog: () => void,
  }
): JSX.Element {
  // ...
}
```

I also gave explicit return type for the ActionsColumnFormatter.